# simple HTML, odd alignment with float seemingly not working

Tags: html, css

HTML below:  (but JSfiddle had both HTML and CSS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="top1">
        <div class="top1-left">
            Welcome, Guest
            <a href="https://www.google.ca">Login</a>
            <a href="https://www.google.ca">Sign up</a>
        </div>
        <div class="top1-right">
            Stay Updated
            <a href="https://www.google.ca">Subscribe via RSS</a>
            <a href="https://www.google.ca">Email Updates</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="top2">
        <div class="top2-text">
            <span style="font-size:40px;">My Blog</span>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left: 40px;"> Description of My Blog</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="top3">
        <div class="top3-text">
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-right: 40px;">HOME</span>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-right: 40px;">ABOUT</span>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-right: 40px;">BLOG</span>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-right: 40px;">CONTACT</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fsf90593/

My question is why the text in the "top3" div not floating to the left just like the other divs? I pretty much have the same css and html code for that div. Probably a simple answer but I am pretty new to the html css world, please help.

Comment: It is because you have 60px padding on left for every div.

Comment: @VXp There is no table objects used here

Comment: @Ofisora How can I acheive the same effect then? I switched to margin instead and am running into the same issue

Comment: @mcgillian Can you post the desired result(screenshot) in any form by updating the question?

Comment: @mcgillian Your question is confusing. The answer to "why is the top3 div not floating" would have to be, "because it doesn't have a `float` property". So I'm assuming that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `clear: both;` on **div.top3-text**

CSS:

```
div.top3-text {
   float: left;
   line-height: 70px;
   padding-left: 60px;
   clear: both;
}
```

It will clear **top3-text** after **top2-text** and allow it to appear below the **top2-text**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  *Just adding a div with a class 'clear' and style that class with 'clear: both'*

```css
div.top1{
    background-color: darkgreen;
    height: 40px; 
}
div.top1-left{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 60px;
    color: white;
}
div.top1-right{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px 30px 5px 0px;
    color: white;
}

div.top2{
    background-color: #247424;
    height: 150px;
}

div.top2-text{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 60px;
    line-height: 150px;
}

div.top3{
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #81EE81;
}
div.top3-text{
    float: left;
    line-height: 70px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}

a{
    color: #82B62E
}

.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="top1">
        <div class="top1-left">
            Welcome, Guest
            <a href="https://www.google.ca">Login</a>
            <a href="https://www.google.ca">Sign up</a>
        </div>
        <div class="top1-right">
            Stay Updated
            <a href="https://www.google.ca">Subscribe via RSS</a>
            <a href="https://www.google.ca">Email Updates</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="top2">
        <div class="top2-text">
            <span style="font-size:40px;">My Blog</span>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left: 40px;"> Description of My Blog</span>
        </div>
    </div>
   
   <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="top3">
        <div class="top3-text">
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-right: 40px;">HOME</span>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-right: 40px;">ABOUT</span>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-right: 40px;">BLOG</span>
            <span style="font-size:20px; margin-right: 40px;">CONTACT</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```